# How can select like % between 2 string of Datatable?

Tags: sql, vb.net

This is my code , i want check a input code exist in Datatable:

```
Dim dtColor = New DataTable
dtColor.Columns.Add("Code")
Dim dr=dtColor.newrow
dr("Code")="AB%M"
dtColor.Rows.Add(dr)
dr=dtColor.newrow
dr("Code")="BCT%"
dtColor.Rows.Add(dr)

Dim strCode="AB100Z"
Dim Arr=dtColor.Select(String.Format("'{0}' like Code ", strCode))
```

But it occur error:

```
Error in Like operator: the string pattern 'AB%M' is invalid.
```

How can select like % between 2 string of Datatable?

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to Dataset with combination of `Regex.IsMatch` as workaround because  `LIKE` operator in `DataTable` filtering only support wildcards at the beginning or the end of statement, as provided in example below:

```
Dim Arr = dtColor.AsEnumerable().Where(Function (row) 
              Dim value = row.Field(Of String)("Code")
              Return Regex.IsMatch(value, "AB.*M")
          End Function).ToArray()
```

If you want to use wildcard characters in all positions like `%AB%M%`, just replace the regex pattern by adding more `.*` as replacement of `%`:

```
Dim Arr = dtColor.AsEnumerable().Where(Function (row) 
              Dim value = row.Field(Of String)("Code")
              Return Regex.IsMatch(value, ".*AB.*M.*")
          End Function).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) and [DB2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzregexp_like.htm&ved=2ahUKEwjTy9Wdha7fAhUDg5AKHf1EDHUQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw0svyjQGiPqgUn6buoKXibX&cshid=1545296370098) have the `REGEXP_LIKE`, [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) have the RLIKE. You can search using a regular expression, which will match your scenario. For VB you can find a workaround to use the REGEX like described below [(reference can be found here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a22cb659-bb13-4579-b082-0b902e4580e0/regular-expression-datatable-filter-vbnet?forum=regexp#f63c4400-73a0-4afb-b915-a2c4e88e9792))

```
Regex rx = new Regex(......, RegexOptions.Compiled );
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   if (rx.IsMatch(row.Field<String>("myRow")))
   {
        ........
   }
   
}
```